# Can someone explain me why these queries have got different execution times?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, delayed-execution

I need to get eight subqueries but they only runs fine as a query, when a use only one of them as a subquery, the execution time passes from 4 seconds to 4 minutes, 60 times more long for the same query and I need seven others.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(benches.name, 1, 2) as Bancada,
    /* USUARIOS - HOMBRES */
    (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SubUser.document) AS '01'
        FROM loan_historical as SubLoan
             LEFT JOIN anchors as SubLoanAnchor ON SubLoanAnchor.uuid = SubLoan.loan_anchor_uuid
             LEFT JOIN benches as SubLoanBench ON SubLoanBench.uuid = SubLoanAnchor.bench_uuid
             LEFT JOIN users AS SubUser ON (SubUser.change_uuid = (
                 SELECT change_uuid FROM users WHERE uuid = SubLoan.use_uuid ORDER BY users.date_change DESC LIMIT 1
             ))
             LEFT JOIN login_cards AS SubLoginCards ON (SubLoginCards.uuid = (
                 SELECT uuid FROM login_cards WHERE use_uuid = SubLoan.use_uuid ORDER BY login_cards.date_created DESC LIMIT 1
             ))
        WHERE SubLoan.use_uuid IS NOT NULL
             AND (SubLoginCards.worker = 0 OR SubLoginCards.worker IS NULL)
             AND YEAR(SubLoan.loan_date_created) = 2019
             AND MONTH(SubLoan.loan_date_created) = 1
             AND SubLoan.use_uuid IS NOT NULL
             AND SubUser.gender = 'M'
             AND SUBSTR(SubLoanBench.name, 1, 2) = Bancada
             AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, SubUser.birthday, '2019-01-01') < 18
        ORDER BY SubUser.document ASC) AS 'UM0017'
FROM benches
ORDER BY benches.name;
```

This is the second query that works fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SubUser.document) AS '01'
FROM loan_historical as SubLoan
     LEFT JOIN anchors as SubLoanAnchor ON SubLoanAnchor.uuid = SubLoan.loan_anchor_uuid
     LEFT JOIN benches as SubLoanBench ON SubLoanBench.uuid = SubLoanAnchor.bench_uuid
     LEFT JOIN users AS SubUser ON (SubUser.change_uuid = (
         SELECT change_uuid FROM users WHERE uuid = SubLoan.use_uuid ORDER BY users.date_change DESC LIMIT 1
     ))
     LEFT JOIN login_cards AS SubLoginCards ON (SubLoginCards.uuid = (
         SELECT uuid FROM login_cards WHERE use_uuid = SubLoan.use_uuid ORDER BY login_cards.date_created DESC LIMIT 1
     ))
WHERE SubLoan.use_uuid IS NOT NULL
     AND (SubLoginCards.worker = 0 OR SubLoginCards.worker IS NULL)
     AND YEAR(SubLoan.loan_date_created) = 2019
     AND MONTH(SubLoan.loan_date_created) = 1
     AND SubLoan.use_uuid IS NOT NULL
     AND SubUser.gender = 'M'
     AND SUBSTR(SubLoanBench.name, 1, 2) = '01'
     AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, SubUser.birthday, '2019-01-01') < 18
ORDER BY SubUser.document ASC;
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056  Please read this, paying particular attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question. With respect, you have not given us nearly enough information to help you.

Comment: yeah, I can't really figure out what you are talking about, but most likely your subquery is running for each result in the main query.  even 4 seconds is a long time for a simple query, so you may need an index.  You have subqueries in your JOIN statements, so that's going to be a nightmare

Comment: Please use **EXPLAIN ** before each query and post the results from the explain as images so we have more info. Note that multiple sub-queries and order by both ruin performance and you used them both nested.

Comment: I have posted the explain result on https://pastebin.com/vb8nzkqy and ulpload an image there: https://pasteboard.co/J91Ww58.png

I think its clear, the database is really huge! I don't know how I can reduce the delays.

Comment: As Garr mentioned, the reason the execution time is longer is that you execute your query for every value of "Bancada" (`AND SUBSTR(SubLoanBench.name, 1, 2) = Bancada` instead of `... = '01'`). You probably have about 60 rows in your table `benches`. If you are happy with knowing WHY, I guess we can write you an answer for it. If you actually want to know how to fasten it, you would need to help us help you, and give us the table structure/explain. Or, better, simplify your problem (and then give us the details), e.g. the problem stays the same without all left joins except `SubLoanBench`.

Comment: To be more precise: you seem to actually have 2 problems. First, to reorganize your dependent subquery on an unindexable column. For this, you can simplify your first query so you only have the left join to `SubLoanBench`. The second task is to get your separate "second query" down from 4s (indexes, rewriting, ...). Both problems can (most likely) be solved independent from each other. Splitting them into 2 questions, each focussing on the specific aspect, makes them cleaner/shorter/easier answerable. (You can add a 3rd on how to combine both answers if you need help with that).

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when `JOIN` is what you need.  In particular for `SubUser`.
- Move the sub-subquery for change_uuid out one layer.  Ditto for the other sub-subquery.
- Use date comparisons instead of extracting DIFF, YEAR, MONTH.
- Switch to `AND SubLoanBench.name LIKE '01%'`.  You can use `CONCAT` to dynamically construct the target of LIKE`, but it may run slower.
- `SubLoan.use_uuid IS NOT NULL` occurs twice.
- If you have a huge table UUIDs are inherently inefficient.
- `(SubLoginCards.worker = 0 OR  SubLoginCards.worker IS NULL )` cannot use an index; consider using either `0` or `NULL`, but not both.  That way this expression can be simplified.
- The `ORDER BY` is irrelevant since there is only one row (with the `COUNT`).
- If all the subqueries are similar, it *may* be practical to do all of them in a single query with a `GROUP BY`?

After you have fixed some of those, I will take a look at optimal indexes.  Meanwhile, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience. I done all features you describe above, but the result does not looks better.

I have decided to get all results in a unique query and then I work with > 1G of rows. I think I can achieve the task easily and faster.

Sorry for my poor English. :(

Comment: @WinterSquad - There could be a quick involving a composite index.